# Move the checkbox in between the two textView

Tags: android, xml, listview, checkbox

How can I move the checkBox in between the Description and Price ?

My desired output should look as image below

[image]

but I only able to do this

[image]

My xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:button="@drawable/xml_button"
        android:background="@drawable/xml_background"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ListAmount"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ListDate"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ListDate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDate"
        android:text="20 Dec"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/input_register"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ListAmount"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ListAmount" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
        android:text="RM 5.00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/violetred"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ListDate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> How can I move the `checkbox` in between the two `textView`,
>   description and amount ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should surround `Description`, `Amount` and `CheckBox` with `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"

        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_below="@id/description"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"

        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Amount"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

By using `RelativeLayout` you have access to `to_RightOf`, `to_LeftOf` and many others, but the most significant one in this case is `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` which will center the element in the parent. In this case it's a very useful help.

Comment: Thanks, but how about my `date`?

Comment: Since the root container is RelativeLayout, for your date element, you can use attribute layout_below="someId" and layout_alignParentRight="true"

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new ConstraintLayout for Android.

It is much easier for your Question.

[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

You can also find a short introduction on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XamMbnzI5vE)

Answer (score 0):

This one will work

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ListDescription"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/xml_background"
    android:button="@drawable/xml_button"
    android:paddingRight="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListAmount"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ListDate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="RM 5.00"
    android:textColor="@color/violetred"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListDescription"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListDate"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ListAmount"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ListDescription"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:text="20 Dec"
    android:textColor="@color/input_register"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```